# Is it possible to apply KNN using quantitative variable?

Tags: pandas, math, statistics

I have this scatter, from quantitative data. Is it possible to apply KNN using quantitative variable?
[image: Scatter]

Comment: Interesting question, but it's off topic for SO. Try stats.stackexchange.com instead. Be sure to say more about what you're trying to do and your own attempt at the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what that would tell you.  This looks more like a variable whose variance increases linearly with X.